# Swipe to go back gesture flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, back, swipe-gesture

How do i implement the swipe from the left to go back gesture in flutter? Not sure if it was already implemented automatically for iOS, but I wanted it for Android as well (as things are becoming gesture based).

Comment: same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894406/how-to-implement-swipe-to-previous-page-in-flutter

Comment: @najeira thanks, will close this!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `CupertinoPageRoute` to make it work on Android;

`import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';`

(as answered on [How to implement swipe to previous page in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894406/how-to-implement-swipe-to-previous-page-in-flutter))

Answer (score 5):

You can set the `platform` of your `theme` (and `darkTheme`) to `TargetPlatform.iOS`, you can set the `pageTransitionsTheme` of your themes to,

```
pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
    builders: {
      TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
      TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
    },
),
```

and you can load the new page using `CupertinoPageRoute` ... and none of that will work until you make sure to use `Navigator.push` (instead of `Navigator.pushReplacement`) to get to that new screen! I hope this helps anyone out there who was working with existing transitions and didn't notice this crucial detail. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could set your Theme.platform to TargetPlatform.ios. This will make use that the swipe back gesture is used on every device.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CupertinoPageRoute()` as [Tom O'Sullivan said above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54170000/11547064).

However, if you want to customize it (eg. using custom transition duration) using `PageRouteBuilder`s and get the same swipe to go back gesture, then you can override `buildTransitions()`.

For iOS, the default `PageTransitionBuilder` is `CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder()`. So we can use that in `buildTransitions()`. This automatically give us the swipe right to go back gesture.

Here's some sample code for the `CustomPageRouteBuilder`:

```dart
class CustomPageRouteBuilder<T> extends PageRoute<T> {
  final RoutePageBuilder pageBuilder;
  final PageTransitionsBuilder matchingBuilder = const CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(); // Default iOS/macOS (to get the swipe right to go back gesture)
  // final PageTransitionsBuilder matchingBuilder = const FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder(); // Default Android/Linux/Windows

  CustomPageRouteBuilder({this.pageBuilder});

  @override
  Color get barrierColor => null;

  @override
  String get barrierLabel => null;

  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return pageBuilder(context, animation, secondaryAnimation);
  }

  @override
  bool get maintainState => true;

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 900); // Can give custom Duration, unlike in MaterialPageRoute

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    return matchingBuilder.buildTransitions<T>(this, context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child);
  }
}
```

Then to go to a new page:

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => Navigator.push(
    context,
    CustomPageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => NewScreen()),
  ),
  child: ...,
)
```

Comment: how about transitionDuration: transitionDuration and reverseTransitionDuration: transitionDuration, parameter ? can u edit your answer for these parameter ?

Comment: @override
  // TODO: implement reverseTransitionDuration
  Duration get reverseTransitionDuration =>
      const Duration(milliseconds: 900); //

Comment: this worked for me like a charm, should be the correct answer! It helps when you are creating a custom pageroute

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin:

https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_back_gesture

A Flutter package to set custom width of iOS back swipe gesture area.
For basic use:

```
import 'package:cupertino_back_gesture/cupertino_back_gesture.dart';

BackGestureWidthTheme(
 backGestureWidth: BackGestureWidth.fraction(1 / 2),
  child: MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
        builders: {
           //this is default transition
          //TargetPlatform.android: FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder(),
          //You can set iOS transition on Andoroid
          TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilderCustomBackGestureWidth(),
          TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilderCustomBackGestureWidth(),
        },
      ),
    ),
    home: MainPage(),
  ),
)
```

More details on plugin's page

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the solution turned out to be very simple. I just used `context.push('screen')` instead of `context.go('/screen')`

Answer (score -3):

This should not be implemented on Android since it makes interactions inconsistent across the OS.

Swiping from the screens edge to go back is not something that Android wants you to implement, so you should better don't do it.

Comment: Although I agree with you from UX perspective, that's not really an answer to the actual question, which is a legit one.

Comment: @Capricorn yep, just wanted to see what it was like for implementation and for feel, but understand that it goes against the MD rules.

Comment: Android Q the recommended way is a back gesture https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/08/gesture-navigation-backstory.html