# How to implement swipe to previous page in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Go back feature works only on the edge of the screen on iPhone. How can I swipe to previous page from anywhere on the screen?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

correct way is :

```dart
MaterialApp(
  .
  .
  .
  theme: ThemeData(
    pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
      builders: {
        TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
        TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
      }
    )
  ),
  .
  .
  .
);
```

Comment: why does not work on my application. using flutte version 1.25.0-9.0.pre.1

Comment: then what ? its not work , ```Navigator.of(context).push(
                            PageRouteBuilder(
                              pageBuilder: (_, animation, __) {
                                return FadeTransition(
                                  opacity: animation,
                                  child: MoviePage(movie: movie),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          );```

Answer (score 2):

Use [CupertinoPageRoute](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPageRoute-class.html) to make it work on Android.

Comment: Could you explain? I try to use `CupertinoPageRoute` - it provides animation in iOS style. But swipe left to right for returning to previous page still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly the problem is how to set custom width of the iOS back swipe gesture area?
So one of the possible solutions is to use this package: [cupertino_back_gesture](https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_back_gesture).

Explanation from authors of package:

To change width of area where the user can start back swipe for the whole app:

- Wrap your `MaterialApp` with `BackGestureWidthTheme` with desired `backGestureWidth`
- set iOS builder of `pageTransitionsTheme` to `CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilderCustomBackGestureWidth`

```
import 'package:cupertino_back_gesture/cupertino_back_gesture.dart';

BackGestureWidthTheme(   backGestureWidth: BackGestureWidth.fraction(1 / 2),   child: MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
        builders: {
          TargetPlatform.android: FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder(),
          TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilderCustomBackGestureWidth(),
        },
      ),
    ),
    home: MainPage(),   
  ), 
)
```

Example app can be found on [github.com](https://github.com/PiN73/cupertino_back_gesture/tree/master/example)

Comment: Does it use with onGenerateRoute?

Answer (score 1):

In materialApp simply set in theme

```
theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.green,
    pageTransitionsTheme: const PageTransitionsTheme(
      builders: {
        TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
      },
    ),
  ),
```

and where you are routing use **CupertinoPageRoute** instead of **MaterialPageRoute** it will work in right way .

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use [swipeable_page_rout](https://pub.dev/packages/swipeable_page_route). It has specific parameter `onlySwipeFromEdge: false`.

Answer (score -1):

You are most likely looking for [`PageView`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) which allows swip to go next/previous page gesture.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know how to implement PageView which allows swipe to go previous page gesture. May you show me an example about that?