# Flutter (webview_flutter) Swipe Back to Pop Webview

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I use the below code for a Flutter Webview (webview_flutter package).

When a Back *button* is clicked, _goBack() sets whether to go back to the previous page, or if no previous page, pops the webview.

I then enabled gestureNavigationEnabled:true to allow the user to swipe back to previous pages.  Works well. However, when there are no previous pages, swiping does not pop the webview.

Is there a way to give swiping back the same behavior as the Back *button*?

1. if previous page exists, swipes to the previous page
2. if no previous page, swipe closes the webview

Thank you.

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

     body: WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _goBack(context),
      child: WebView(  
        initialUrl: widget.url,
        gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controllerCompleter.future.then((value) => _controller = value);
          _controllerCompleter.complete(webViewController);
      ),
    ),

      Future<bool> _goBack(BuildContext context) async {
        if (await _controller.canGoBack()) {
          _controller.goBack();
          return Future.value(false);
        } else {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          return Future.value(true);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Use [CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894406/how-to-implement-swipe-to-previous-page-in-flutter) to swipe and pop the screen

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is the 'Context' when it found no context it doesnt close the webview window .so in this case what you need to do is :

> Look at this here:
> https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux/issues/5#issuecomment-361215074

```
You can set a global key for your navigation:

    final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

Pass it to MaterialApp:

    new MaterialApp(
          title: 'MyApp',
          onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
          navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        );

Push routes:

    navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed('/someRoute');
```

You Need to Create a Global Key for Navigation and then it can work . it will close the window without getting the context (means if the previous page is not there then it can also pop the window )