# Swipe back in flutter. without any button

Tags: flutter, dart

How Can I swipe for back in Flutter? not tap back button.
***Without any button......***
Just swipe from left to right. And go to the back page
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap your screen widget with gesture detector and on detecting swipe left you can pop the screen like this

```
GestureDetector(
  onPanUpdate: (details) {
    if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
  },
  child: Scaffold(
    body: ///your body
  ),
);
```

Edit:

The above solution was the one that came to my mind and i got another answer on stack-overflow maybe that one is the correct way to do it here is the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55577584/14466860